# Get the JSON value by a specific key

Tags: javascript, json, key, key-value

I'm almost finished with extracting the value from the JSON string. When I do `console.log(rs.query.pages[19].revisions[0])` I get

```
Object {key1: "value1", key2: "value2", *: "value3"}
```

But, all I need is to extract `value3` only.
How to get that value by the key *?

When I try (and of course it won't work)
`console.log(rs.query.pages[19].revisions[0].*)` I get

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ***

What's the correct way to get `value3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put "*" as a string in square brackets:

```
console.log(rs.query.pages[19].revisions[0]["*"])
```

That'll always work, regardless of how "messy" the property name is.  When property names look like valid JavaScript identifiers, you can use the `.` notation.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(rs.query.pages[19].revisions[0]["*"])`